# determine if a string contains numbers in octave

Tags: string, octave

I'm new to Octave so I'm not really familiar with how to manipulate strings. I can't find any built in functions to determine if a string contains a certain type of character. This is a simple question, is there a built in function for determining if a string is alphanumeric, numeric, etc. ? If so, what is it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`isstrprop`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/isstrprop.html) with a specific category;

```
octave> all(isstrprop('1234', 'digit'))
ans =  1
octave> all(isstrprop('123a', 'digit'))
ans = 0
octave> all(isstrprop('123a', 'alnum'))
ans =  1
octave> all(isstrprop('123a.', 'alnum'))
ans = 0
```

Comment: @HaroldDecapia Accepting answers that answer your question is better than thanks. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers